# Number that's not a given number

Tags: javascript, pseudocode

In my JavaScript file, I have a `var`iable `num` with a value of `3`. What I wanna do is get any number that is not `3`, between `1` and `4`. To give you an idea of it:

```
if number equal 3
  return [1,2,4]
elif number equal 1
  return [2,3,4]
elif number equal 2
  return [1,3,4]
elif number equal 4
  return [1,2,3]
```

Comment: just remove num from [1,2,3,4] using slice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and return the unequal values.

```js
function getArrayWithout(array, v) {
    return array.filter(function (a) { return a !== v; });
}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(getArrayWithout(array, 3));
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the if/else to do so. You could just define which is the number that you want to exclude and then filter it out from the numbers array.

```js
var numberToExclude = 3;
var numbers = [1,2,3,4];
console.log(numbers.filter(number => number !== numberToExclude));
```

For further info, regarding the `filter` method please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example).

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the range using a simple for loop and generate array by checking the number.

```js
function genArray(num, start = 1, end = 4) {
  // initialize the result array
  var res = [];
  // iterate based on the range
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++)
    // push into the array if number is not `num`
    i != num && res.push(i)
  // return the result
  return res;
}

console.log(genArray(3));
console.log(genArray(2));
console.log(genArray(3, 1, 10));
console.log(genArray(3, 2, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do with [`Array#splice`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiJqOSMlaHUAhVBsY8KHfCpAx8QFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fsplice&usg=AFQjCNHJstEQi0lf1yjpJBRFo9iN5hXxkQ&sig2=gEqGajpL2EqO7HbavCHOaA) method

```js
function except(num){
var arr=[1,2,3,4]
if(arr.indexOf(num) > -1)
arr.splice(arr.indexOf(num),1);
return arr
}

console.log(except(3))
console.log(except(1))
console.log(except(2))
```